# Kafka Streaming Reset Issues

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have been attempting to build a Kafka Streaming application for use with Spark. I have a static dataset for testing. After running my code once through, Kafka sets the current offset such that I cannot re-process the data upon a second run. Running `kafka-streams-application-reset` supposedly resets the offsets. However, re-running my code results in an empty `GlobalKTable`. The only way I have been able to re-analyze the data is by changing my ID in my Kafka connection. Here is what I'm doing.

Setup the sample data in Kafka:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 \
    --topic testTopic \
    --property "parse.key=true" \
    --property "key.separator=:"

1:abcd
2:bcde
3:cdef
4:defg
5:efgh
6:fghi
7:ghij
8:hijk
9:ijkl
10:jklm
```

Scala code:

```
//Streams imports - need to update Kafka
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes
//import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes
import org.apache.kafka.streams._
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.{GlobalKTable, KStream, KTable, Materialized, Produced, KStreamBuilder}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.{KeyValueIterator, QueryableStoreTypes, ReadOnlyKeyValueStore, KeyValueStore}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.Stores
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, KafkaConsumer}
import java.util.{Properties}


val kafkaServer = "127.0.0.1:9092"
val p = new Properties()
p.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "testStream")
p.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer)
p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass())
p.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass())
p.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
p.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-stream")
val config = new StreamsConfig(p)


val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
val imkvs = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("testLookup-stream")
val sBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(imkvs, Serdes.String, Serdes.String).withLoggingDisabled().withCachingEnabled()

val gTable: GlobalKTable[String, String] = builder.globalTable("testTopic", Materialized.as(imkvs).withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(Serdes.String()).withCachingDisabled())
val streams: KafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config)
streams.start()

val read: ReadOnlyKeyValueStore[String, String] = streams.store(gTable.queryableStoreName(), QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore[String, String]())
val hexLookup = "2"
println(read.get(hexLookup))

val iter: KeyValueIterator[String, String] = read.all()
while(iter.hasNext) {
  val next = iter.next()
  println(next.key + ": " + next.value)
}
```

Streams Reset command:

```
kafka-streams-application-reset --application-id testStream \
    --bootstrap-servers localhost:9092 \
    --to-earliest
```

1) Am I coding something wrong, or is `kafka-streams-application-reset` not functioning correctly?
2) I had hoped that using a `inMemoryKeyValueStore` would result in Kafka not keeping track of the current offset; is there a way to force a `GlobalKTable` to not keep the current offset? I want to always search the entire dataset.

Software Versions:
Kafka 1.1.1-1
Confluent 4.1.1-1
Spark-Scala 2.3.1
kafka-clients 1.1.0
kafka-streams 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart an application from an empty internal state and re-process the data from offset 0, you have to provide "**--input-topics**" parameter with comma seperated list of topics.

```
bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --application-id testApplication1  --input-topics demoTopic1
```

You can find more details here : https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool

Regarding GlobalKTable, ideally it is materialized view on top of stream/topic just like any other queryable store.
***Also GlobalKTable always applies "auto.offset.reset" strategy "earliest" regardless of the specified value in StreamsConfig.***
So it should allow you to query the entire table at any time.

Comment: Today I deleted my topics to recreate and test your solution. This time my test code functioned as I expected - no offsets were stored for the stream. Not sure what happened there...

With `auto.offset.reset`, it is my understanding that this settings only comes in to play when there is no offset already defined for the topic/application-id combo. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, `auto.offset.reset` is the fallback when there are not offsets. However, Kafka streams does not commit offsets for `GlobalKTable`s in the first place, but tracks offsets in a local `.checkpoint` file -- there was a bug with regard to in-memory `GlobalKTable` in 1.1.0 release that is fixed in 1.1.1, so you should not hit it. In general Kafka Streams uses more advance patterns internally that a plain consumer, and in-fact, Kafka Streams uses 3 `KafkaConsumers` internally...